# Proof for this partition graph

Tags: number-theory, integer-partitions

Consider the below graph for 7. Each node represents a unique partition of 7. I notice that we can reach to any node from the bottom  by partitioning only even integer except the bottom node. I have tried it for other numbers. For instance, number 5,6,8 and found that it works. Will this works for any number or not I do not know? mathematically I am unable to prove it. Could you please help me regarding this. [image]

Comment: Also posted, for no good reason, to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285260/proof-for-this-partition-graph with no mention at either site of the post at the other site.

Comment: Oh sorry, I couldn't know that both sites are linked. Thanks it wouldn't happen again.

Comment: When you post the same question to two sites, you should mention on both sites that you have done this, whether the two sites have any relation to each other or not. It's a matter of common courtesy. Better yet: don't ever post the same question to two different sites, at least not until you have put in the effort to understand the response you got on the first site.

Comment: Thanks. I will edit there.

Answer (score 3):

Consider any partition $P$ that has at least $3$ pieces. At least two of those pieces have the same parity. Pick two pieces with the same parity and merge them, i.e., replace them by their sum. Since the sum is even, the new partition $P'$ that you produced is joined to $P$ by an edge in your "split only even integers" graph. Continuing in this way, you can produce a path in your graph, heading from $P$ downward toward the root, until you get down to a partition with only two pieces. Then, you're just one step from the root, and your graph has an edge to the root even if the root is odd.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. Will this work for any integer $n$ ?

Comment: This seems to work for any positive integer in place of $7$.

Comment: Thanks. I thought both are different sites so posted. Thank you for your explanations.

Comment: I was in doubt "At least two of those pieces have the same parity". Here same parity means both are same number or both have same property like Even, Even or Odd, Odd . But later found that its either even,even or odd,odd.